# Updating/Animating vertices of a 3d Model from OBJLoader in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load a 3D model and animate its vertices. I succeed in loading the model however not been able to animate the vertices.
My code is here:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('assets/models/head/lee-perry-smith-head-scan.obj', function (object) 
{
    var faceMaterial = getMaterial('standard', 'rgb(255,200,200)');
     object.traverse(function(child) 
     {
        if (child.name == 'Infinite') 
        {
            child.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            child.material = faceMaterial;
        }
    });
    object.children.forEach(function(vert)
    {
    vert.geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(vert.geometry);
        vert.geometry.vertices[0].set( 0, 2, 5 );
    })
```

Comment: Why are you doing: `vert.geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(vert.geometry);`?

Comment: @Mugen87 unable to access vertices otherwise

Comment: Instead of creating a `Geometry`, try it like this: 

`var position = vert.geometry.attributes.position;`
`position.setXYZ( 0, 0, 2, 5 );`
`position.needsUpdate = true;`

Comment: Also see https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things

Comment: @Mugen87 Thank you!
It seems i am able to access just one vertex rather than all the vertices with this method